# get list of collections having all words exists in field which added in given string in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, string, mongodb, find

I want to search list of collections from mongoDB have all the keywords of given string.

For e.g.

```
I have a collection 
{
  "id":1
  "text":"go for shopping",
  "description":"you can visit this branch as well"
}
{
  "id":2
  "text":"check exiting discount",
  "description":"We have various discount options"
}
```

Now, If I will pass string like **"I want to go for shopping"** w.r.t. text field in find query of mongoDB. Then I should get first collection as output because text  field value "go for shopping" exists in the input string passed in find query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved through $text operator in MongoDB. But you have to createIndex on the "text" field in your database.(or whichever filed you want to be matched, I would suggest you rename it in your db to avoid confusion)

```
db.yourCollectionName.createIndex({"text":"text"})
```

The first field here is the "text" field in your database, and the second one is the mongo operator.

Then you can pass any query like,

```
db.yourCollectionName.find({$text: {$search: "I want to go for shopping"}})
```

The "$text" here is the mongo operator.
This would return all documents which have any of the keywords above.

Maybe you can read more around this and improvise and modify.

Ref: [MongoDb $text](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is working But. 

I just checked this query db.yourCollectionName.find({$text: {$search: "shopping"}}). it still show returns me first collection. Is it possible. Query will return data if and only if full word like "go to shopping" in DB match with part of input string. So in my query. it should not return any result.

Comment: I will have to check. If I get time, will surely let you know. Meanwhile you can do some R&D in mongoDB documentation. You might find a way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so through regular expression. MongoDb provides the provision of matching strings through regex patterns.
In your case you could do something like:

```
db.yourCollectionName.find({text:{$regex:"go for shopping" }})
```

This will return you all the documents having the phrase "go for shopping" in the text field.

Ref: [MongoDb Regex](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_regular_expression.htm)

Comment: I cannot pass partial string. User can input full sentences "I want to go for shopping" in find query. I want to find records that will match with the text fields. As I have mentioned in my question

db.yourCollectionName.find({text:{$regex:"I want to go for shopping" }})

Then first record should be select because input string have same keywords saved in DB

Comment: I have added another answer for this. You can check that out.